# What protocol should I use for a general ecoacoustics study (using Acoustic Indices)?

Tags: monitoring

We recently asked the question above to delegates at the UKAN+ Monitoring Biodiversity symposium, using a SurveyMonkey Questionnaire, and with the following parameters:

> We want to develop a broadly applicable acoustic monitoring method, useful for a range of studies, enabling common approaches and data sharing. The questions below aim to see whether any consensus can be reached on aspects of sampling design.
> Your answers should assume that you are designing a realistic general-purpose ecoacoustic sampling protocol for monitoring the soundscape of a site, e.g. for environmental assessment, nature reserve management, or a rewilding scheme. The model study will be:
>
> 1. implemented for a single discrete site, not a wide
>    regional/national scheme,
> 2. be based in UK/Europe,
> 3. undertaken by an organisation with limited means, e.g. a county
>    Wildlife Trust, landowner, or ecological consultancy,
> 4. Use 5-10 commercially available automated recording units, and
> 5. have data analysis to produce Acoustic Indices, or identify species presence
>    primarily within the audible range, e.g. birds or amphibians.

**What would your advice be in terms of equipment setup, programme, and spatial and temporal deployment?**

Of course there is no one correct answer, or one-size-fits-all.  But I'm keen to see where there is consensus - and disagreement.

Answer (score 3):

The Survey Monkey Questionnaire we posed to delegates at the symposium, and online via Twitter, gained 84 respondents. The answers they provided are here:

https://github.com/carlosabrahams/Bioacoustics_Course/blob/f1b6282577a9ace7b085a22ebab4a500e950d8c8/Resources_Reading/UKAN_Questionnaire_Responses_220701.pdf

(Hope that link works for everyone..)

Thanks, Carlos

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you've come across it already or not, but a good place to start would probably be this publication (https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/2041-210X.13254). It (or the authors) might be able to answer some of your questions.

Comment: Frowin, thanks.  Hi - yes, Tom and I know each other, and he contributed to the questionnaire too.  Larissa Sugai's articles are also super-useful.

Comment: Ah, I see. My apologies. The results of this questionnaire are very interesting.